# how can I change with 1 button 2 labels (2 player game)

Tags: c#, wpf, class, button, label

I have a 2 player dice game. 1 button has to change with every click the player who plays and changes the score for that plays. I have found a solution for the button that needs to change the player but I'm stuck with the score. Now it changes both labels, I know why but I can't find the solution. This is my code so far.

The dice class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameLib
{
    public class Dobbelsteen
    {
        public int aantalOgen;
        static Random rnd = new Random();

        public Dobbelsteen()
        {
            Dobbel();
        }

        public Dobbelsteen(int aantalOgen)
        {
            this.aantalOgen = aantalOgen;
        }

        public void Dobbel()
        {
            aantalOgen = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        }
```

The game class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameLib
{
    public class Vijftig
    {
        public Dobbelsteen steen1 = new Dobbelsteen();
        public Dobbelsteen steen2 = new Dobbelsteen();

        public int score;
        public int waarde;


        public int score1;
        public int score2;

        public void Speel()
        {
            steen1.Dobbel();
            steen2.Dobbel();

            if (steen1.aantalOgen == steen2.aantalOgen)
            {
                if (steen1.aantalOgen == 6)
                    score += 25;
                else
                    if (steen1.aantalOgen == 3)
                        score = 0;
                    else score += 5;
            }
        }
```

The xaml.cs:

```
using GameLib;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfVijftig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Vijftig spel = new Vijftig();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (spel.waarde = 1; spel.waarde < 7; spel.waarde++)
            lbWaarden.Items.Add(spel.waarde);
        }

        private void btnSpelen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            spel.Speel();


            int score1 = 0;
            int score2 = 0;

            imgDobbelsteen1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/" + spel.steen1.aantalOgen + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            imgDobbelsteen2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/" + spel.steen2.aantalOgen + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));

            if ((string)btnSpelen.Content == "Gooien speler 1")
            {
                btnSpelen.Content = "Gooien speler 2";
                lblScoreSpeler1.Content = score1 + spel.score;
            }
            else if ((string)btnSpelen.Content == "Gooien speler 2")
            {
                btnSpelen.Content = "Gooien speler 1";
                lblScoreSpeler2.Content = score2 + spel.score;
            }
            if (spel.score >= 50)
                MessageBox.Show("Je hebt gewonnen!!!");

            Debug.Print("je gooide " + spel.steen1.aantalOgen + " en " + spel.steen2.aantalOgen + ". Je score is " + spel.score);
        }
```

Comment: While people can help you fix this I recommend you do a tutorial on MVVM and bindings. That xaml.cs file should be practically empty.

Comment: Hi, I'm starting from zero and had this exercice I have to make. It's about working with classes. I searched allready on the www and bindings is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

First tip for you is to code in english which makes your code easier to understand.

I think you want to retrieve the clicked button from the listener try doing like this:

```
int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;

private void btnSpelen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
    if((string)clickedButton.Content == "Gooien speler 1")
    {
            score1++;
    }
    else if((string)clickedButton.Content == "Gooien speler 2")
    {
            score2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the button content stays the same and the score only goes up for player 1. With this code I play with one player.

Comment: i still having the problem that the score for the 2 players stays the same. If player 1 gets 5 points, after the next click player 2 gets also 5 points. Isn't it possible to change the code in the game class? So that there are in the game class 2 scores or players. Now I have to use the INT score from the game class but it's only one and I have to use it twice. That's the reason I think I still having this problem.

Comment: Try to use the debugger which might help you !
and / or update your code in english so that it can be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try to move declaration of variables used to store scores to be a class scoped variables :

```
Vijftig spel = new Vijftig();
int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;
.......
private void btnSpelen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    spel.Speel();

    //remove local declaration of score1 & score2 from here

    ......
    ......
}
```

Your existing code will reset both scores to zero upon every button click because they are declared locally. Those scores are disposed and recreated on every click event triggered.

Comment: Hi, I allready tried this. The problem is that if the score raises for example for player 1, that with the next click the score for player 2 also goes up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Don't know if it's the best one but it works fine. 
Thanks for helping finding a solution!

This is the essential code in the game class.

```
public int BerekenScore(int score)
    {
        if (steen1.aantalOgen == steen2.aantalOgen)
        {
            if (steen1.aantalOgen == 6)
                score += 25;
              else
              if (steen1.aantalOgen == 3)
                  score = 0;
                else score += 5;
        }
        return score;
    }

public void Speel()
    {
        steen1.Dobbel();
        steen2.Dobbel();
    }
```

This is the essential code in the main.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Vijftig spel = new Vijftig();  

private void btnSpelen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        spel.Speel();
        ToonStenen();

        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
        if ((string)clickedButton.Content == "Gooien speler 1")
        {
            clickedButton.Content = "Gooien speler 2";
            spel.score1 = spel.BerekenScore(spel.score1);
            lblScoreSpeler1.Content = spel.score1.ToString();
        }
        else if ((string)clickedButton.Content == "Gooien speler 2")
        {
            clickedButton.Content = "Gooien speler 1";
            spel.score2 = spel.BerekenScore(spel.score2);
            lblScoreSpeler2.Content = spel.score2.ToString();
        }

public void ToonStenen()
    {
        imgDobbelsteen1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/" + spel.steen1.aantalOgen + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        imgDobbelsteen2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/" + spel.steen2.aantalOgen + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```